# How do I read the top record in a Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the top record of the message section of my database, check that the email value doesn't match the users email. If it does, then repeat with the next record down. But if it doesn't match, I want it to populate a textview in my app with its 'message value' and then delete the record from the database.

Here is an example of my write to database code:

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

 //setting user info in message class
 message m = new message();
 m.setName(user.getDisplayName().toString());
 m.setMessage(messageEdt.getText().toString());
 m.setEmail(user.getEmail().toString());

 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("messages").child(uniqueGeneratedMessageid);

 myRef.setValue(m);
```

That adds it to the data base like so...

[image]

I want it to select the top value whatever it may be, without having to reference the specific `ygmailcom100`.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question instead of commenting with code like below?

Comment: ok sorry, new here

Comment: That's fine. It's just hard to read your code comments to understand what you are trying to ask about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query mQuery = database.child("messages").limitToLast(1);
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you are trying to load messages from a chat app. If that is the case, I'd recommend you add `ChildEventListener` instead of a `ValueEventListener`, the main reason being `ChildEventListener` will return only the newly added message, where as `ValueEventListener` will return both the newly added message and the whole database Snapshot each time a new message is added. That will be very costly in terms of efficiency and data usage, wait time, etc.

From what you gave me above, you would implement a `ChildEventListener` like this:

```
private final ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private final Query mQuery;
private final FirebaseDatabase database;

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mQuery = database.child("messages").limitToLast(1);

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); 
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

};

```
mQuery.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
mChildEventListener = childEventListener;
```

Then in your `onDestroy` method, you will want to remove the `ChildEventListener` to avoid memory leak.

```
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (mChildEventListener != null) {
  mQuery.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
 }
}
```

Comment: when i use this it returns all the values from the key 'message', i just need 1 (any random one).

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know. Thanks

Comment: you will have to forgive me i am new to firebase. this is what i input:

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages");
        Query mQuery = myRef.child("messages").limitToLast(1);

Comment: mQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
                    message.setText(value);
                }

Comment: that returns DataSnapshot{key messages, value= null}